# setUserAgentString Android Studio

Tags: android, user-agent

I am trying to change the useragent in Android Studio with the following code but will not work?  Any ideas?

Thanks

private WebView mWebView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forums);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewf);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("AndroidApp");
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("my URL");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though the version numbers are out of date, I found your question as I'm looking for the current strings (in one place)

I do belive android 4.1 and up force system to use chromium upgrades? In the standard WebView

```
WebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4; Nexus 4 Build/KRT16H) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30");
```